# MySQL Show Profiles

Tags: mysql, sql

can  someone help me with the following sentence  from the MySQL Homepage.

> In addition, profiling is per process and not per thread. This means that activity on threads within the server other than your own may affect the timing information that you see.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html

I  want to get the duration of a query. Simultaneously 9 other querys from other clients try to get information from the database. 
Do I  only get the information for my query or  do i also see the information of the other querys? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This may pertain to MySQL Cluster where the database is stored on multiple machines. Are you working in such an environment?

Comment: My database is stored on online one  Computer and the other clients try to access the database with different Isolation levels.

Comment: You're probably not impacted by this differentiation then as there will be only one MySQL server process.

Answer (score 0):

This disclaimer ( *profiling is per process and not per thread* ) means the information about your query's reported performance will be affected by the other workload on the MySQL server. The server tries to sort out your query's resource usage from the other workload, but due to various limitations it cannot do that perfectly accurately.

It warns you that profiling on a busy MySQL server will not yield completely reproducible results.   This isn't generally surprising.  As long as you take your profile measurements as appropximations, you probably won't have trouble.

Comment: I am testing the effect of isolation levels to the time that is needed to finish a query when 10 clients try to get access to the database simultaneously. Therefore I have  to measure the time of every single query and I try to do  this on every Computer for its queries. If I get you right, its possible to get the time with all other effects with the Show profiles Statement, right?